# Duplicate Posts Showing in a Slider

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php function to call in Wordpress posts and display them as a slider, I want to limit the maximum number of posts shown to 4, but instead, I get the same 4 posts repeating three times. What should I change?

```
<?php

$args = [

    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [
                'post-format-aside',
                'post-format-link',
                'post-format-quote',
                'post-format-status',
                'post-format-audio',
                'post-format-chat',
                'post-format-video',
            ],
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ],
    ],

];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
    return;
}
?>


<div class="author-recent-posts">

    <div class="author-recent-posts__header clear row">
        <div class="author-recent-posts__header__inner large-7 small-12 column">
            <h2>From The Carlyle Financial Blog</h2>
            <a href="/blog/">View All <i class="fa-solid fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="author-recent-posts__slider">

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            $thumb = [get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/carlyle-financial-music-background.jpg'];
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            endif;
            $thumb = sprintf( 'style="background-image: url(\'%s\')"', esc_url( $thumb[ 0 ] ) );
            ?>

            <div class="author-recent-post-item">
                <div class="author-recent-post-item__inner">

                    <a class="author-recent-post-item__link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                        <span class="sr-only"><?php _e( 'Read more' ); ?></span>
                    </a>

                    <figure class="author-recent-post-item__thumb" <?php echo $thumb; ?>></figure>

                    <div class="author-recent-post-item__header">
                        <?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title">', '</h3>' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.author-recent-post-item__header -->

                </div>
                <!-- /.author-recent-post-item__inner -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.author-recent-post-item -->

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /.author-recent-posts__slider -->
</div>
```

I try reducing `'posts_per_page' => 4`, to the number I need, but the maximum number doesn't change, it creates duplicates instead

Comment: This looks fine. Do you actually use the `post_formats` on your site? Also try updating the opening `if` statement to remove the `return()` and check `if ( $query->have_posts() ) :` and put the `endif;` after you markup.

Comment: Which slider do you use?